# How do you save new users in AngularFire?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase, angularfire

I'm trying to create users via the `$createUser` method which is part of the firebase simple login service.

The AngularFire/Firebase documentation discusses adding additional data to a user object -- username, etc. -- but I'm confused as to how to save the user created with `$createUser` to Firebase itself as

```
{
  "users": {
    "simplelogin:1": {
      "provider": "password",
      "email": "something@some.com"
      "provider_id": "1"
    },
  }
}
```

My Firebase is currently completely empty and I'm trying to use the below controller code to create a new user.

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', '$firebase', '$firebaseSimpleLogin',
  function ($scope, $firebase, $firebaseSimpleLogin) {
    var ref = new Firebase('https://socialfiction.firebaseio.com/');
    var sync = $firebase(ref);

    $scope.auth = $firebaseSimpleLogin(ref);

    var currentUser = $scope.auth.$getCurrentUser().then(function(user, err) {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err);
      }else{
        console.log(user);
        return user;
      }
    });

    $scope.createUser = function() {
      $scope.auth.$createUser('jamie.smith@email.com', 'password').then(function(user) {
        sync.child('users').child(user.uid).$set({
          // not sure if this is right?
        });
      });
    }

  }
]);
```

I guess my question specifically is what do I need to add to my `$scope.createUser` function to properly `$set` the new user to a `users` object inside of my firebase?

Comment: What version of AngularFire is this? Also, none of the AngularFire versions have a `.child` method. It's also unclear what you need $firebase for here. Why not just call ref.child('users/'+user.uid).set(...)?

Comment: It's angularfire 0.8. And you need to inject $firebase into the module/controller -- https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/angular/quickstart.html

Comment: So why not just call ref.child('users/'+user.uid).set()? And $firebase still does not have a .child() method.